# strategy on how to tackle

Tags: prepositions

*At the moment, the country has no strategy on how to tackle this threatening problem.*

Is it really necessary to use the preposition "on" in the bellow sentence? I have found plenty of sentences where "on" after "strategy" not to be used.

Comment: Google Books has just one instance of [*tackle this threatening problem*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tackle+this+threatening+problem%22), and even that looks to be from a non-native speaker (in Hong Kong). But there are 7 instances of [*tackle this **looming** problem*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tackle+this+looming+problem%22), even though ["looming" is far less common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=looming%2Cthreatening&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clooming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthreatening%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: ...in your context, the idiomatic preposition+verb combination is *a strategy **for tackling** [the problem],* or ***...to tackle it***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native speakers say all of the below:

> They have no strategy for herding the cats.
>
> They have no strategy on how to herd the cats.
>
> They have no strategy how to herd the cats.

To my ear, **strategy for** is the most idiomatic, and Ngram bears that out.